# How can I send js mediaStream to server and return the processed stream?

Tags: websocket, webrtc, mediastream

I want to send live webcam stream from website to my server, and the server will do some processing on the frames and return the processed stream. I'm thinking about using WebRTC to send live stream to server (server as a peer), and return the processed frames by images via WebSocket. Is there any easier way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

WebRTC.getUserMedia can capture video stream, but you cannot send them to your server.(you can do this if your server can parse them to a complete picture)

So the easier way to finish this problem is that post the picture which captured by webrtc.getUserMedia to server, and then your server return the processed picture. You can use canvas to show those pictures.

You can read this [Computer Vision on the Web with WebRTC and TensorFlow](https://webrtchacks.com/webrtc-cv-tensorflow/)